# Is there a sexier datacenter than Bahnhof's "Pionen"?

Tags: datacenter

I mean really...
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

> [pictures](http://www.bahnhof.se/pionen/gallery/)... [article](http://royal.pingdom.com/2008/11/14/the-worlds-most-super-designed-data-center-fit-for-a-james-bond-villain/)... [architectural appreciation](http://www.archdaily.com/9257/pionen-%E2%80%93-white-mountain-albert-france-lanord-architects/)

Comment: Looks like a mix of the Batman cavern and the headquarter of one of those James Bond villains. :-)

Comment: So yeah my favorite part is the forest-planter-thing next to their generator room...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly you haven't seen MareNostrum.

http://images.google.com/images?hl=en&q=marenostrum&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=wi

[image]

Comment: MareNostrum isn't strictly a data center, afaict

Comment: Wow... we need a tag for "cable-porn", (the TP kind, not the TV kind).

Comment: +1 Okay, I can only vote this up once but that is beautiful, and voting it down because it's a grid instead of a datacenter seems just a little pedantic

Comment: it's not a grid, it's a high performance cluster. And HPC clusters live in datacenters. I worked with HPC for 3 years.

Comment: do you want my vote or not ;-) whatever it is, it's beautiful.

Comment: It's kind of hard to escape the "priesthood" analogy with the IT department.

Comment: More pictures: http://blogs.oracle.com/simons/date/20070811

Answer (score 3):

The Fortress of Solitude. Admittedly it does not actually exist, but the location is genius: zero fan noise, and no need for climate control

[image]

Comment: “launch JorEL”.. silence.. “run JorEL?”.. silence.. “exec JorEL?”.. silence.. “crap! superman_do launch JorEL!”... "VOICEPRINT ID ACCEPTED, LOADING JOR-EL CONTROLLER"

Comment: @jorel# make me-a-sandwich..  @jorel# sudo make me-a-sandwich